# searchTwitter returning an "empty" list

Tags: r, twitter

i'd appreciate some help. i am trying to use `searchTwitter` from the `twitteR` package and i typed the following command

```
> tws<-searchTwitter('#NASCAR',n=10) 
#when i tried to inspect the content of tws, i get the following:
> tws 
[[1]] 
character(0)
```

I am a newbie and i am not sure if this has to do with authentication or the RCurl package. Can someone please tell me how to fix this? I have searched the forunm and I couldn't find something directly relevant. any help is appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using? Ruby?

Comment: Geez ! Look at me. I am extremely sorry to have left that information out. I am using R. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: Your code runs ok on my machine, and returns 10 tweets in a list. Do you see any warning?

Comment: Thanks flodel but unfortunately, it doesn't on mine. Is there some authentication I should have taken care of before using this ? I also suspect that the source of the RCurl package I used might be a problem. Is this a possibility ? I am actually more baffled now that you confirm it's not a syntax problem but rather something a little more foundational in nature. I'll appreciate it if anyone who knows what the source of the problem is can help. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and I got 10 tweets as well.

Do you have bitops and rjson installed?